# Thymeleaf dymamic text tag

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In the controller, I am adding a bunch of attributes to the model like `test_1`, `test_2`, `test_3`. In thymeleaf, I want to use those attributes in a text tag like `th:text="${test_1}"`. However, the text is within a fragment, so I want to dynamically set the number in the tag. I feel like the key is using th:with, or preprocessing, but I haven't found something that works. Here's what I tried.

`th:with="i='test_' +${number}"  th:text="${i}"`

`th:text="'test_' + ${number}"`

`th:text="${'test_'+__${number}__}"`

All of these simply have test_1 (or whatever number is specified) as the output, instead of pulling that value from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```html
<div th:text="${__${'test_' + number}__}"></div>
```

This uses something very similar to your 3rd example, but it places the entire string concatenation inside a preprocessor.

Test data:

- `number` is set to `2` in your Java/Spring model.
- `test_2` is set to `"bar"` in your Java/Spring model.

Explanation:

1. First, use the preprocessor syntax to build the string you want - where that string matches a variable in the model:

   `__${'test_' + number}__`

The above Thymeleaf expression evaluates to the string `test_2`.

2. Because this was a pre-processed variable, it effectively becomes the following, when it is wrapped inside a `${...}`:

   `${test_2}`

The above evaluates to the string `"bar"` - which is what you want.

---

"*the text is within a fragment*": I am not sure what the relevance of that is. It should not matter. If I have misunderstood, maybe you can edit the question to clarify.